# FB.Event.subscribe does not work when click fb like or unclick

Tags: android, facebook-like

I would like to get fb like or unlike event in android . But the FB.Event.subscribe method does not fire . It is strange because my javascript code is work on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/javascript-console/ but not my application.
I know that my question already ask by other people . But I still get this problem. I try many condition , but not work. How can I solve it.

Here is my webview code..

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div> 
 <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
  appId      : '578995225546624',
  status     : true,
  xfbml      : true
});
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
   function(response) {
   var likeFlag = "1";
     alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
     Android.showToast(likeFlag);
   }        
);
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove',
  function(response) {
  var likeFlag = "0";
     alert('You UNliked the URL: ' + response);
       Android.showToast(likeFlag);
  }
);
 };
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=578995225546624&version=v2.0";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));  
 </script>
 <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/testpage" data-layout="standard"   data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
```

Comment: Nobody answer my questions :(

Comment: I don't get answer yet :(